# Is it possible to find an element using multiple words using By.CLASS_NAME in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

I am working on a browser bot and have encountered a problem. Every documentation has an example where an element is found(by class_name) using only one string that represents a class. My problem is that I want to use more than one string(more than one word) to find a class(to be more specific). Here is what every example shows:

```
browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "text-orange-400")
```

And here is what I want to do:

```
browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "text-orange-400 transition hover:opacity-70")
```

Is it possible to do so?

I have tried using many torturous and outrageous ways that I have no intensions in listing in this post. So just help me pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
To locate element based on multiple class name values you should use CSS Selector or XPath.
CSS_Selector:

```py
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".text-orange-400.transition.hover:opacity-70")
```

XPath

```py
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='text-orange-400 transition hover:opacity-70']")
```